# vuejs 3 antd - Failed to resolve component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've imported Antd into my vuejs 3 project, by following the full import guide: https://next.antdv.com/docs/vue/getting-started/#_3-Use-antd-s-Components

Main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';

createApp(App).use(router, VueAxios, axios, Antd).mount('#app')
```

Homepage.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about pages</h1>
  </div>
   <div>
    <a-steps progress-dot :current="1">
      <a-step title="Finished" description="This is a description." />
      <a-step title="In Progress" description="This is a description." />
      <a-step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." />
    </a-steps>
    <a-divider />
    <a-steps progress-dot :current="1" direction="vertical">
      <a-step title="Finished" description="This is a description. This is a description." />
      <a-step title="Finished" description="This is a description. This is a description." />
      <a-step title="In Progress" description="This is a description. This is a description." />
      <a-step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." />
      <a-step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." />
    </a-steps>
  </div>
</template>
```

Error observed in console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-step
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38
resolveAsset @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6002
resolveComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5951
render @ AboutView.vue?c4d7:2
renderComponentRoot @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:893
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5030
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5156
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4939
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4897
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4489
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5107
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:394
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:285
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:279
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5139
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1001
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3187
eval @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3060
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3030
push @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:2962
install @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3376
use @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:3808
eval @ main.js?fbea:9
./src/main.js @ app.js:74
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:616
(anonymous) @ app.js:1812
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:670
(anonymous) @ app.js:1813
(anonymous) @ app.js:1815
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-steps
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38
resolveAsset @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6002
resolveComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5951
render @ AboutView.vue?c4d7:2
renderComponentRoot @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:893
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5030
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5156
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4939
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4897
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:4489
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5107
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:167
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:394
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:285
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:279
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5139
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
eval @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1088
triggerEffects @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:359
triggerRefValue @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:957
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:1001
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3187
eval @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3060
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3030
push @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:2962
install @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:3376
use @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:3808
eval @ main.js?fbea:9
./src/main.js @ app.js:74
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:616
(anonymous) @ app.js:1812
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:670
(anonymous) @ app.js:1813
(anonymous) @ app.js:1815
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: a-divider
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Seems I must be missing an import statement somewhere?
I have not imported anything into App.vue, if required?

Comment: The template root requires exactly one element.

Comment: @EhsanAhmadiKian not sure I understood you

Comment: He means to say there can only be [one root element per component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html?redirect=true#A-Single-Root-Element), but that's no longer required in Vue 3. And it's not the actual problem here. The problem is your Antd plugin was never actually installed properly, but that's resolved in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164952/vuejs-3-multiple-plugins).