# vuejs 3 multiple plugins

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

How can I use multiple plugins within vuejs 3?

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';

createApp(App).use(router, axios, Antd).mount('#app')
```

Within `Main.js`, this seems to import router and axios, but not Antd. If I take off router, and axios then I can see antd components.
How do I bring in everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each plugin must be in its own `app.use()` call:

```js
createApp(App).use(pluginA).use(pluginB).use(pluginC).mount('#app')
```

However, `axios` is *not* a Vue plugin, so don't install that with `app.use()`.

Your code should look similar to this:

```js
createApp(App).use(router).use(Antd).mount('#app')
```